# CodeIgniter security measures

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I used PHP without any framework, I would validate a post with something like this

```
$username = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));
```

but in CodeIgniter I do something like

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
```

does CodeIgniter clean the string or I have to do it?

Comment: WRONG. you don't do a database escape to "validate". that's NOT what m_r_e_s() is for. validating is "is this empty? does it contain what it should?". you also **NEVER** post-process data after doing a db escape. you can completely undo the escaping and still do an SQL injection on yourself.

Comment: so whats the best practice for this using codeigniter? A code sample would be great! Thanks

Comment: Codeigniter docs are possibily the best among the major php frameworks. You can start from there.

Comment: There is no possible security issue in the code you've posted, because all it does is access a POSTed variable. You are definitely using `mysql_real_escape_string` incorrectly though. You escape your values at the last possible second before they're written to a database, on the way *out* of your app, preferably by whatever database library/ORM you're using. You do not escape them on the way *into* your app, that renders them useless for processing by your app.

Comment: @meagar but then I have to check the username in database if it exists or not.

Comment: Then *that* is where you should be escaping them. Your database layer should accept regular, unescaped data as input, escape **internally** as required to build queries, and then return regular, unescaped data.

Comment: ohhh, that makes more sense.. so whats the way to escape the string in codeigniter, I am in the docs and I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Moreover, don't use mysql_real_escape_string(), use query binding or Active Record class, they'll escape everything for you; again, it's in the docs. As for the string, what do you want to escape? The string is not malicious in itself. If you mean _befor outputting on the page_, pass a true as second parameter to apply the XSS filter, or just use htmlentities(). Read the database section, the Input section, the Security section

Comment: It keeps mentioning that _All values passed to this function are escaped automatically._ but it doesn't say that particularly for select function, does that mean I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter's input class fetches all information from `$_POST` via the `xss_clean()` filter method in the security class.

The [documentation for this method](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html) and indeed its very name suggest that this is not a query string sanitizer (as proposed in the question). Instead, CI cleverly performs the sanitization before performing queries when using the database driver and **bindings**.

An adaptation of the [database queries documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) under "Query Bindings":

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ?";

$this->db->query($sql, array($this->input->post('id')));
```

Comment: What if I want to use the select(), where() and other functions, instead of writing the sql myself. What the "?" still be used the same way?

Comment: Use Active Record OR query binding (this one is used when queries are passed as regular SQL). Really, man, take SOME MORE TIME to read the docs, not just one line and then you rush here asking for something.

Comment: I have read most of the documentation. Anyways, thanks for however you tried to help

Comment: @Grigor yes, the Active Record implementation does escaping by default. For your reference, [here is the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).

Comment: For the record, $_POST is not passed through xss_clean() by default, only if you activate it in the configs, or if you pass TRUE as second parameter of $this->input->post().

Comment: @DamienPirsy Good catch Damien!

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter automatically sanitises a string when using the built in [Database Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).

In your question you're only accessing the input value but not doing any processing or database activity at all.

You can use the [Form Validation Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) to do any validation on that input you're accessing, but this is done in the controller that calls the Form View, not the form processing controller.

Comment: Note that "validation" != "sanitation". A wrong email format is not "valid" but is "safe". A text input with "<script>some malicious js;</script>" is valid and _might_ be unsafe if printed out _as is_ on the page; and so on

Comment: That's why I talked about sanitation with the Database Library (which has that functionality included, among others) and about validation in the Form Validation Library...